# Citrix dynamic virtual channel error: Cannot find a transport to support DVC

Tags: c#, dynamic, virtual, channel, citrix

I'm having trouble getting a dynamic virtual channel created between the Citrix server and the local PC.  The error that is coming up on the server side is:

CSession::CreateDynamicChannel:Cannot find a transport to support DVC=

I have a C++ COM dll registered as a plugin on the local PC and it appears that it is being loaded correctly by the Citrix Receiver's virtual channel manager (my trace logging from initialization through to attaching a listener to the end point indicates that all is working fine).

However, when we start the executable on the Citrix server, we get the error mentioned above.  The executable is a C#/.Net application.  The error occurs in response to my call to WTSVirtualChannelOpenEx.

My function prototype in C# for that function is as follows:

```
[DllImport("wtsapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern IntPtr WTSVirtualChannelOpenEx(
    [In]
    [param: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]
    int SessionId,
    [In]
    [param: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
    string VirtualName,
    [In]
    [param: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
    int flags);
```

My actual call to the function is as follows:

```
_vcHandle = WTSVirtualChannelOpenEx(
    (int)Session.WTS_CURRENT_SESSION,
    pluginName,
    (int)(DynamicChannel.WTS_CHANNEL_OPTION_DYNAMIC | DynamicChannel.WTS_CHANNEL_OPTION_DYNAMIC_PRI_HIGH)
    );
```

The value for "pluginName" is a 7-character string loaded from a config file.

The Citrix documentation on dynamic virtual channels says simply to follow the Microsoft API on both the client and server ends, which I've done.  That documentation specifies how to register the plugin on the client but doesn't stipulate having to do anything extra on the server.

From my understanding, the virtual channel manager on the server gets a list of names of plugins from the virtual channel manager on the client.  The server-side virtual channel manager then stores the names in a table.  Thereafter, when any program requests a connection via a dynamic virtual channel to a client-side plugin, the server-side virtual channel manager looks up the name in the table and then sends the connection request through to the client.

Is there possibly something in the setup that needs to be done.  For example, does a dynamic virtual channel need to be assigned by an administrator to a specific static virtual channel number, or does the virtual channel manager take care of that dynamically (hence the name "dynamic") at the time that a request is made?

I haven't been able to find any references, in documentation or in searching the Web, to the sort of error that we're experiencing.

Answer (score 1):

No there's no assignment of VCs for dynamic VCs. They work by getting multiplexed over the one static (underlying) VC.

What name are you using for the "pluginName"? If you look at the vdping sample that comes with the SDK you will see a line in the client code for the DriverOpen implementation as follows:

```
OpenVirtualChannel.pVCName = CTXPING_VIRTUAL_CHANNEL_NAME;
```

This constant is defined in the associated vdping.h header file:

```
#define CTXPING_VIRTUAL_CHANNEL_NAME  "CTXPING"
```

So if I then wanted to open this VD on the server I would need to use "CTXPING" as the plugin name, which you can see in the associated server sample code in ctxping.c in the SDK (note the samples are quite old, so they're using the Citrix WF APIs, using WTSVirtualChannelOpenEx is also fine):

```
hVC = WFVirtualChannelOpen( WF_CURRENT_SERVER,
                            WF_CURRENT_SESSION,
                            CTXPING_VIRTUAL_CHANNEL_NAME );
```

Apart from that you just have to ensure you have properly followed the registration steps and added the necessary registry keys. Note that the docs were created pre-x64. So while the docs state:

```
HKLM\Software\Citrix\ICA Client\etc...
```

You need to ensure you use the 32 bit registry hive instead since the Windows client is 32 bit:

```
HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\Citrix\ICA Client\etc...
```

Comment: Thanks.  The name that I'm using is fine but your advice about the registry keys could be a pointer to the problem.  I'll experiment with the registry keys under which the plugin is listed and will post a comment here about the outcome. Cheers